# How get all products with images in magento

Tags: php, magento

i want to show all products with name and image. Please check my code,

This is my controller:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'descryption'))
        ->setPageSize(10);
$numberOfPages = $model->getLastPageNumber();
$data['products'] = $model->setCurPage($i)->load();
```

and this is my view:

```
<?php 
foreach ($data['products'] as $product) { 
    $productName = $product->getName();
?>
        <div class="celeb-post" id="products-listing">
                <img src="<?php ?>" alt="celeb" />
                <div style="clear:both; height:10px;"></div>
                    <div class="celeb-name-title ucase clearfix" style="text-align:center;"><?php  echo $productName ?></div>
                </div>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

Name of product is showing but how can i get image? Any one help to find product image and display in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach($products as $product)
{
$image = $product->getImageUrl(); 
$product_image_url_gallery = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();

$galleryURL = '';
foreach ($product_image_url_gallery as $image) {
    $galleryURL .= Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $image->getFile()).'<br>';
}

echo $product->getName().'<br>';
echo $image.'<br>';
echo $galleryURL.'<br>';
}
```